# Complex string vector creation from data frame values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which has only one column called Values and a list of string values:

```
Values
AA
AB
CG
DS
KI
```

Is there a simple way to create a string vector with each value separated by |?
The desired resulting output should look something like this:
`Vector = "AA|AB|CG|DS|KI"`

Cheers!

Comment: paste(dframe$Values ,collapse = '|') you mean something like this? Or could you clarify your point and desired output?

Comment: yes correct, thanks. You can place it as an answer so I can give you the answered question.

Comment: It is written already, however thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you simply use (assuming your data is called `df`):

```r
paste0(df$Values, collapse = "|")
```